Why does this casing int pointer to a char pointer not work in C?
I know there are better alternative ways to getting ASCII codes of a char but I am really struggling to understand why this code "1680146529" instead of '97'. It doesn't seem to be printing an address or anything like that and there's a clear pattern where if I change the value of *p to "b", the last two numbers change from '29' to '30'. Been trying to figure out how this number forms.
int main() {
    const char *p = "a";
    int *a = (int *) p;
    printf("%d", *a);
}

I have tried printing the addresses of the variables and pritning different values and trying increase the size of *p and find a more clearer pattern with a bigger string but couldn't figure out anything.
I also tried to change my *p to be of four bytes. So instead of just "a", it stores "abcd" and the result was: 1684234849. This doesn't make sense to me...
For more context, A similar code to was used in the "collision" challenge in pwnable.kr where taken a password, this type of casting was applied to it to generate a hashcode. I was trying to solve that..
Solution---->>>>>
Okay sorry guys this was a bit of a dumb question. So the answer IS the ASCII values concatinated as @user17732522 said in the comments. It's just the hexadecimal ASCII which is then converted to integer...

How do you expect *a to work? Where should it take its value from and what is stored there?

And questions of what bytes will be read to produce the value aside, this violates the so-called strict aliasing rule. Attempting to read from a char (array) object through a int pointer is simply specified to have undefined behavior.

"and the result was: 1684234849. This doesn't make sense to me..": This looks exactly like the value I would expect. What do you expect instead?

If you expect it to just produce 97, i.e. if you just want to change the type while keeping the value of p[0], then why are you casting pointers? You would simply need int a = p; instead.

I thought it'd result in something like "979899100" or some form of combinations of the ASCII values of the String..

@Ferrrerero It is the values concatenated, but there is no reason to assume that in decimal. Each individual byte has a range of 256 values, which is not a power of ten. But it is a power 2 and of 8 and of 16, so you can see the concatenated values in binary, octal or hexadecimal, e.g. 1684234849 = 0x64636261 which happens to be the hexadecimal ASCII values of d, c, b and a with the order that way, because your system happens to be little-endian, i.e. interpreting the bytes in memory with increasing significance from lower to higher address.

@user17732522 omg I see it now.  So that's the hex ASCII value concatenated together and converted to decimal that makes so much sense. So obvious but for some reason, I did not think of that. I've been sitting here trying to see why this was the case. Thank you very much.

You seem to assume that dereferencing the int* variable would read from memory at the address where "a" is stored. That does not need to be the case. If the location of the string does not start at an address that meets the alignment requirements for an int you might start reading at an address that does. For example, a CPU might ignore the least 2 address bits when reading a 32bit value. No matter if your string starts at address, 100, 101, 102, or 103, it could start at address 100. Or it could just crash.

As an aside, I find it amusing that while (int *) p is garbage, (int) *p would give you the ascii value of 'a'.

On most systems a char is a single byte, while the type int is usually four bytes. When you fetch the value of *a, where will the other three bytes come from?
What you're doing is breaking the strict aliasing rule, and leads to undefined behavior.
When passed as an argument to printf, all types smaller than int (i..e char and short) will be promoted to int.
So if you want to print the integer value of the character 'a' then just print it as an integer:
printf("'a' == %d\n", 'a');

Or for your case:
printf("'%c' == %d\n", p[0], p[0]);

If you want to be very specific you can use the hh prefix, as in
printf("'%c' == %hhd\n", p[0], p[0]);


To give you more details about what's happening, the variable p is pointing to the first element (first byte in the case of char) of an array containing two elements:

      +-----+------+---------+---------+-----+
p --> | 'a' | '\0' | garbage | garbage | ... |
      +-----+------+---------+---------+-----+

Only p[0] and p[1] are valid for the string, the data after that is garbage (actually it's indeterminate, but it might be better to think of it as garbage).
When you dereference the pointer variable a, you will read four bytes, and the program will use all four bytes to construct the int value. The exact order in which the bytes are used depends on the system endianness. Most PC systems are little-endian.
Now because there are two bytes that are garbage (really, indeterminate) you will get a garbage result.
